# bitbucket pipeline with docker, how to add source dependencies from a git repo

Tags: docker, ros, bitbucket-pipelines

Im using ROS industrial CI with pipelines. It fails to build because of a dependency on a package that I have to build from source.

Normally I would clone the source git repo and just build it. But I don't know how to specify that dependency on pipelines.

```
git clone https://github.com/AprilRobotics/apriltag.git      # Clone Apriltag library
cd april*
cmake .
sudo make install
```

Would appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Well, let me share with you my approach on that. I use GitLab CI, which I guess it might be similar.

In my repository, I have a *rosinstall* file including the packages that I need to build from source.

In my case, *coscr.rosinstall* looks like

```
- git:
    local-name: ira_laser_tools
    uri: https://github.com/iralabdisco/ira_laser_tools.git
    version: master
```

Then in my *.gitlab-ci.yml* file, I handle it like that:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

image: osrf/ros:melodic-desktop-full

before_script:
  - apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
  - apt-get install -y python-rosinstall python-rosinstall-generator python-wstool build-essential
  - apt-get install -y alsa-utils
  - apt-get clean
  - mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd ~/catkin_ws/src 
    - git clone https://gitlab.com/______/cs_monster.git
    - cd ~/catkin_ws 
    - wstool init src src/cs_monster/coscr.rosinstall
    - rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y
    - catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

You can see how I use *rosdep* to make the trick.
As far as I remember it was working. Either way, I hope it can give you some hints.